# Prevent image display until all images load

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a webpage. On this page there is a portfolio grid of downloadable resources that are represented with pictures. Currently if someone tries to change the filter before all of the images load it will break it.

I would like those buttons to not be clickable until all of the images on the screen have loaded, and I would like to do so using JQuery.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: write code to detect/count images as they load, then check if the count is correct in your click handler before letting the click through... or just not attach the click handler until loading is completed.

Comment: Removed unnecessary link to a real site to avoid your post being deleted as spam.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Shouldn't you fix the issue that causes your grid to break if the filter is applied before the images are loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the filters container that prevents interaction such as:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}

<div id="filters-container" class="cbp-l-filters-alignCenter disabled">
```

And then use the initComplete.cbp event from the plugin to remove it.

```
$("#grid-container").on('initComplete.cbp', function() {
    $('#filters-container').removeClass('disabled');
});
```

Comment: Excellent thank you! I am still open to other suggestions if people have them, but this one sounds efficient and simple.

Comment: I applied this suggestion and unfortunately it does not seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hide all images by default using CSS

```
    img{
    display: none;
    }
/* disable all buttons using class disabled*/

.disabled{
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Use Jquery to check if all loaded, then display images and enable buttons

JQuery

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $('img').fadeIn(800); //or $('img').show('slow');
   $('.disabled').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
});
```